# Generate code coverage report outside of PHPUnit

Tags: php, xdebug

I want to generate phpunit code coverage on my own, but so far it wasnt succeed. From here: https://gist.github.com/christeredvartsen/5128598 with this code:

```
<?php
xdebug_start_code_coverage(XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED | XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE);

// other codes

$data = xdebug_get_code_coverage();
xdebug_stop_code_coverage();
$coverage = new PHP_CodeCoverage();
$coverage->append($data, 'some-id');
$report = new PHP_CodeCoverage_Report_HTML();
$report->process($coverage, '/tmp/coverage-report');
```

it wont generate anything but a Total 100.00% covered (success) line. Even though my whole project is covered and run.

Answer (score 1):

okay, Im figured out myself.
Instead of:

```
$coverage->append($data, 'some-id');
```

use

```
$coverage->setData($data, 'some-id');
```

!!